# Sm Shopby Cannot Initialize Reindexer Process

Tags: error, mysql, indexing

I seem to be having an issues indexing on Magento. All available indexes index fine except for one:

Sm Shopby

When indexing through the following error, but I can't quite see what the issue is.

````
Sm Shopby index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`main_table`.`frontend_input`' in 'where clause'' in /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php(29): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php(20): Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute->reindexSeoUrlKeys()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#18 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`main_table`.`frontend_input`' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `additional_table`.* FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id WHERE (`main_table`.`entity_type_id` = '4') AND (```main_table```.```frontend_input``` IN('select', 'multiselect'))' in /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php(29): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php(20): Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute->reindexSeoUrlKeys()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
````

I've looked in the `Pdo.php` file but I'm not 100% sure what I'm after. I tried a couple of queries which managed to fix Product Flat Data & Category Flat Data, but not this specific index.

Any clues?

Comment: Magento Could not find colunm name 'frontend_input' in your DB

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have installed the latest security patch or are starting from Magento 1.9.2.2?

Notice that the failing query contains duplicate backtick quotes around table alias and field name:

````
AND (```main_table```.```frontend_input``` IN('select', 'multiselect'))'
````

It looks like the extension is not compliant with SUPEE-6788.

### Fix

Search for calls to `addFieldToFilter` in the extension code and look for backticks (``) and just remove them in the first function argument.

The call should be somewhere around here or where the collection is built: `app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php(29)`

### Technical Details

The technical details page for SUPEE-6788 at http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details says:

> APPSEC-1063, addressing possible SQL injection
>
> Modules that use SQL statements as field names or escape fields manually will need to be modified.
>
> Developers will need to change the way they generate filters for collections.